# How to render video from ARGB Frames

Tags: c#, wpf, rendering, argb

I'm using the `Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC` library and I am planing on using it for my next project - a Real-Time video chatting app.
I have been able to establish a connection and pass video frames around.

**How would I properly render those Frames and display them as Video?**

Using WPF's `MediaElement` seems pretty easy, but I can only input an `Uri` object as source, I cannot feed it single frames, AFAIK.

I have read that drawing Bitmaps is a possible solution, but I am sure this would mean many hours reinventing the wheel and testing, which I am not a fan of doing, unless there is no other way.

*The library works as follows:*
Each time a new frame is received by the client the `Argb32VideoFrameReady` event is raised. A `Argb32VideoFrame` struct object is then passed to the callback, which contains an `IntPtr` to the raw data. `Height`, `Width` and `Stride` are also provided.

[More Information on the specific struct here](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.Argb32VideoFrame.html)

What would be some ways I could achieve this?

I am planning on using WPF.
The solution should target Windows 7+ and .Net Framework 4.6.2.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Since you already have the raw pixel data, you may perhaps just write it into a WriteableBitmap. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.writepixels?view=netcore-3.1 Or copy it into its BackBuffer in a background thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.backbuffer?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an Image element in XAML

```
<Image x:Name="image"/>
```

the simple method below would directly copy the frame into a WriteableBitmap that is assigned to the Image's Source property.

```
private void UpdateImage(Argb32VideoFrame frame)
{
    var bitmap = image.Source as WriteableBitmap;
    var width = (int)frame.width;
    var height = (int)frame.height;

    if (bitmap == null ||
        bitmap.PixelWidth != width ||
        bitmap.PixelHeight != height)
    {
        bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(
            width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }

    bitmap.WritePixels(
        new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height),
        frame.data, height * frame.stride, frame.stride);
}
```

ARGBVideoFrame from here: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC/blob/master/libs/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC/VideoFrame.cs

`PixelFormats.Bgra32` seems to be the proper format, due to this comment on the struct:

> The ARGB components are in the order of a little endian 32-bit integer, so 0xAARRGGBB, or (B, G, R, A) as a sequence of bytes in memory with B first and A last.